Azure Key Vault Disabled public access, how to access it through the portal via internet
I have some Key Vaults in my Azure account, these were kept as "Allow public access from all networks", now it had to be changed to "Disable public access" and me along with the team are not able to list the Keys and scerets
I changed it to Allow public access from specific Vnet and IPs, it worked for me and I have to now add public IP of all the other team members like this
Is there a better way to approach it
How bad is keeping the Public access open and the impact is same for other servcies like the Storage accounts
There were logic apps integration with this Key Vault and now it also started failing
Added public IP addresss of mine and it worked, but adding everyone's IP doesnt seem like a productive approach

There is no one right answer to this. It just depends how far you want to push the security dials and what risks you want to mitigate.
Leaving public access on means that if someone manages to steal credentials that have rights to that Key Vault, they will be able to extract data from that vault. On the other hand, this is the easiest approach.
Restricting access to only the IP addresses of who/what needs access reduces that threat somewhat as they would also need to be in one of those allowed ranges to extract data. Setting up the allowed addresses can take time, especially if the addresses change. This could be alleviated if your team used a VPN to a network that actually has a static address range.
Taking it further, we could disable all public access entirely and use private endpoints. At this point, in order to extract data, the attacker would need to be inside the virtual network. We can also use network security groups to lock down access further to only specific addresses/ranges within the VNET. Now accessing the vaults would become harder for your team and require use of something like Azure Virtual Desktop or Bastion to get to a machine that is inside the network. Or by using point-to-site or site-to-site VPN.

Its more of like I have to add everyone's public IP address who would be accessing the Key Vault right

How are other resources in Azure affected, as it is Key Vault it will be integrated with many other Azure services right, one of my logic apps failed after I disabled public access
Does the Private Endpoint have any extra cost along with it?

Yeah, so you need to find out what the addresses for the Logic App are and add them as allowed as well. I'm not sure how it goes with Logic Apps, but in App Service for example those outbound addresses are usually shared with other Azure customers who have their app deployed to the same server cluster. Just something to keep in mind. Private endpoints do have some cost in that the endpoint itself costs a small amount. With some services, they need to be upgraded to Premium etc. tiers to support private networking. Not sure about Logic Apps.

In Logic Apps there are Runtime outgoing IP address, Access endpoint IP address and Connector outgoing IP address
and these have many IP addresses inside these categories
If I have to add, do I have to add every IPs?

Yeah, you will have to add multiple addresses most likely as those server clusters have a set of addresses they may use (since you can only have a limited number of ephemeral ports in use per address).

To limit user access to the Azure keyvault, you can whitelist their (Public/Internet) IP address in the key-vault networking firewall setting.
You will have to add each colleague's public IP address OR office public IP address by clicking the plus button. See below.


Wont the public IP address change with respect to the connection?

Yes, it changes unless your colleagues are not using a static IP address from the ISP. The key-vault firewall needs to be updated whenever the public IP address changes on the client side.
